# PyInstaller Winerror3 : System cannot find path specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a executable using pyinstaller using the command :

```
pyinstaller <script>.py
```

It worked perfectly fine in Linux but somehow this does not seem to work on windows.

```
Python : 3.5

Pyinstaller : 3.4
```

But it constantly keeps throwing error for system could not find the path specified     : 
    C:\folder\build\scriptname

Whereas build folder is usually created after the execution of PyInstaller command.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.4', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 741, in build
    os.makedirs(pth)
  File "c:\program files\python 3.5\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\cms\\build\\cmstest`

EDIT : Yes the script is working, script has no issues on Win 10, Fedora 28 or using IDLE .

EDIT : I am getting a .spec file and an empty dist folder

EDIT : Here is my spec file

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['cmsnewtest.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\cms'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='cmsnewtest',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True ) `
```

Comment: You need to post the traceback received while running the command.

Comment: Updated the question with traceback.

Comment: Are you running it as administrator? Perhaps the folder cannot be created due to permissions.

Comment: Yes I made sure the folder has all the permissions from all the users, it did not work too.